# Como fazer um gráfico pizza (pie) com banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

Tenho a tabela no meu banco de dados chamado votes, nela tenho id, name e votes (quantidade de votos), queria plotar esses valores sendo, nome e valor em uma grafico pizza ou seja qual é a porcentagem de votos tem cada nome

```
<?
      $SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM votes";

       $result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
       $data1 = array();
       $data2 = array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
           $data1[] = $row['name'];
           $data2[] = hexdec($row['votes']);
       } 
?>

<script src="js/grafico/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/grafico/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('#graficoPizza').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grafico Plataforma SMS'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Quantidade enviados',
            data: [
                [<?php echo join("','", $data1) ?>,  <?php echo join(',',$data2) ?>]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
</script>

<div id="graficoPizza" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: poderia postar o [tag:json] que é retornado por `data: [[<?php echo join("','", $data1) ?>,  <?php echo join(',',$data2) ?>]]` ? É um fator essencial para poder saber o que está acontecend com seu código

Comment: http://crissite.com/GFILA/index.php?pag=grafico

Comment: Sou meio leigo em javascript estou aprendendo agora mais o json é o que o retorna ou seja valores?

Comment: O seu *data* deve ser assim `data:[{
 name: 'Fulano',
 data: [49.9]
}, {
 name: 'Cicrano',
 data: [83.6]
}, {
 name: 'Beltrano',
 data: [48.9]
}, {
 name: 'Arlindo',
 data: [42.4]
}]`

Comment: tabela do banco de dados: votes  id=1 name= cristiano vote=1,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que seu gráfico pizza do [**hightcharts**](http://highcharts.com) funcione bem você precisa que seu [json](/questions/tagged/json) esteja sendo gerado corretamente de acordo com o modelo

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
        ['Fulano',   27],
        ['Cicrano',       32],
        ['Beltrano',    25],
        ['Toinho',     12]
    ]
}]
```

Como você pode ver no [**grafico dos pé de cana**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LdJj/) esse formato define como as informações serão apresentadas no grafico

Desta forma você teria que formatar seu dados para que eles possam se adequar ao gráfico.
Este deve ser seu [php](/questions/tagged/php)

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM votes";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data[] = array($row['name'], hexdec($row['votes']));
}

$jSon = json_encode($data);
```

E o seu [js](/questions/tagged/js) deve ficar assim:

```
$(function () {
    $('#graficoPizza').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grafico Plataforma SMS'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Quantidade enviados',
            data: <?php echo $jSon;?>
        }]
    });
});
```

Isso resolve seu problema e você terá um gráfico [**assim**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LdJj/2/)

Comment: Cara você é 10.... se tiver alguma maneira de que eu possa te gratificar por essa ajuda me fale E-mail: cristiano@crissite.com   Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Marca a resposta como correta que pra mim é mais que suficiente, hehe. Estamos aqui para ajudar, assim é que a comunidade se fortalece.